# String of variable length to int array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing

I have a string which is in the form 
"1 2 8 4 9 0 " etc. I know it will follow the format of integer, space, integer...

However, I can't guarentee the length. I know the maximum length, if that helps. 
I thought to use sscanf, but it needs a finite number of integers.

Any ideas how I can turn "1 2 3 " into an array where

A[0] = 1

A[1] = 2

A[2] = 3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) indicates where in the string it failed.
For a string like `"1 2 3 ..."` it will read the `1` and fail right afterwards; if you then pass that failure point (`" 2 3 ..."`) to `strtol` it will read `2` and fail right afterwards, ..., ...

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char input[] = "6 82 -7453 4 0 63 ";
  char *err = " ", *curr = input;
  int x, k = 0;
  while (*curr && isspace((unsigned char)*err)) {
    x = strtol(curr, &err, 10);
    printf("#%d: %d\n", k++, x);
    curr = err + !!*err; // do not advance past the '\0'
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/TuaU7)** -- unlike the snippet above, the one at ideone initializes `k` with 1 :/ and doesn't deal well with inputs that end in whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
rc = sscanf(string, "%d%n", &array[i], &len);
```

In a loop. Test the rc, and use len to skip to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not that complicated:

1. Calculate the length of the string with `strlen`
2. Allocate enough memory for the array with `malloc`
3. Iterate over the string again and populate the array

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/e4BaH)**.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more? How can I deal with something like "1 2 23 400 2 1" ? It's the 'iterate over the string' that I can't quite wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many ways could be to use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to tokenize the string with the separator as space & the return value of each `strtok` call can be used with `sscanf` for single integer. As you know the maximum length you can iterate the array to be used with `sscanf` something on [these lines](http://ideone.com/Erifd).
Hope this helps!